# Open new window in chrome HTML

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have a local HTML script which I have written. It essentially asks for text and then on button click will paste that text to a new window.

It has always worked fine in internet explorer, however, I have been trying to get it to work on Google Chrome.

I have tried multiple different methods suggested on here, but I just can't get it to work. I was wondering if anyone had any ideas!

Currently what works for internet explorer to open a new tab and past content is:

```
   var newWindow=window.open();
   newWindow.document.write(sec1 + sec2 + sec3);
```

I've tried things such as the below, but to no avail.

```
var myWindow=window.open("chrome://newtab");
myWindow.onload=function(){this.document.write('textHere')
```

Comment: so is there an error in the developer console? What does not work?

Comment: Microsoft should have disabled Internet Explorer in February 2023.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to open a new window and write inside it I do it this way

```
newWindow=window.open("","New Widnow");
newWindow.document.write("The text I want to write");
```